# Get Stylesheet To Showup in WP Admin Panel Editor

Tags: wp-admin, css, editor, links

So I have a css file that is called `blue.css` and a universal one called `style.css` I have a few css colors inside a `/css` folder. How do I get all those css files to show up in my Admin panel editor?

Comment: Admin panel editor?

Comment: Yeah, I have a css file in `css/blue.css` but it isn't showing up in the admin panel editor. What can I do to make it show up there?

Comment: OK, the *visual editor*. I had no idea what you were talking about ... it sounded like you had an editor for the "admin panels."  But I see you got your answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `add_editor_style()` function in your functions.php:

```
add_editor_style( 'css/blue.css' );
```

You can call that function multiple times to load additonal stylesheets in to the admin editor.